# How to correctly convert from rgb565 to rgb888

Tags: java, colors, bit-manipulation, processing

I'm trying to convert a value from rgb565 to rgb888 but I can't seem to get it right.
I've also checked a few existing answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073426/onpreviewframe-byte-to-int/11075255#11075255) but there are values that don't seem to be properly convert.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
PImage picker;
int c;
void setup(){
  size(285,240);
  picker = loadImage("hsv.gif");
  int c = color(255,255,255);
  byte[] word = colorToWord(c);
  int[] rgb = wordToRGB(word);

  noStroke();
  fill(c);
  rect(0,0,50,100);
  fill(rgb[0],rgb[1],rgb[2]);
  rect(50,0,50,100);
}
void draw(){
  image(picker,0,0);
  if((mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <= picker.width)&&
     (mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= picker.height)) c = picker.get(mouseX,mouseY);

  byte[] word = colorToWord(c);
  int[] rgb = wordToRGB(word);
//  int[] rgb = rgbWordToRGB(word);
  int cc = color(rgb[0],rgb[1],rgb[2]);

  fill(c);
  rect(0,159,142,80);
  fill(cc);
  rect(142,159,143,80);
  fill(0);
  text("original\n"+hex(c),10,185);
  text("converted\n"+hex(cc),152,185);
}

byte[] colorToWord(int c){
  int r = (c >> 16) & 0xFF;
  int g = (c >> 8)  & 0xFF;
  int b =  c        & 0xFF;
  return new byte[]{(byte)((r&248)|g>>5),(byte)((g&28)<<3|b>>3)};
}
int[] wordToRGB3(byte[] data){
// Reconstruct 16 bit rgb565 value from two bytes
  int rgb565 = (data[0] & 255) | ((data[1] & 255) << 8);

  // Extract raw component values (range 0..31 for g and b, 0..63 for g)  
  int b5 = rgb565 & 0x1f;
  int g6 = (rgb565 >> 5) & 0x3f;
  int r5 = (rgb565 >> 11) & 0x1f;

  // Scale components up to 8 bit: 
  // Shift left and fill empty bits at the end with the highest bits,
  // so 00000 is extended to 000000000 but 11111 is extended to 11111111
  int b = (b5 << 3) | (b5 >> 2);
  int g = (g6 << 2) | (g6 >> 4);
  int r = (r5 << 3) | (r5 >> 2); 
  return new int[]{r,g,b};
}
int[] wordToRGB2(byte[] word){
  int r = word[0]&248;
  int g = (word[0]<<5) | ((word[1]&28)>>3);
  int b = word[1] << 3;
  r <<= 3;
  g <<= 2;
  b <<= 3;
  return new int[]{r,g,b};
}
int[] wordToRGB(byte[] word){
  int c = (word[0] << 8) | (word[1]);
  //RGB565
  int r = (c >> (6+5)) & 0x01F;
  int g = (c >> 5) & 0x03F;
  int b = (c) & 0x01F;
  //RGB888 - amplify
  r <<= 3;
  g <<= 2;
  b <<= 3; 
  return new int[]{r,g,b};
}
final int RGB565_MASK_RED       = 0xF800;
final int RGB565_MASK_GREEN     = 0x07E0;  
final int RGB565_MASK_BLUE      = 0x001F; 

int[] rgbWordToRGB(byte[] word){
 int rgb565 = (word[0] << 8) | (word[1]);
 int[] rgb24 = new int[3];
 rgb24[2] = (rgb565 & RGB565_MASK_RED) >> 11;     
 rgb24[1] = (rgb565 & RGB565_MASK_GREEN) >> 5;  
 rgb24[0] = (rgb565 & RGB565_MASK_BLUE);  

 //amplify the image  
 rgb24[2] <<= 3;  
 rgb24[1] <<= 2;  
 rgb24[0] <<= 3; 
 return rgb24;
}
```

using this image as a colour palette:

[image: hsv]

The problem is with certain values:

[image: rgb565 to rgb888 issue]

Why does that happen ? Is there a way to fix that ?

Comment: Hey dude :D if I may add a bit of code to help with the debugging in your draw function: for(int i = 0; i < picker.width; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < picker.height*.5; j++) {
      int ccc = picker.get(i,j);
      byte[] wordle = colorToWord(ccc);
      int[] rgbn = wordToRGB(wordle);
      set(i,(int)(j+picker.height*.5),color(rgbn[0],rgbn[1],rgbn[2]));
    }
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok so here's the fix if I understand correctly:

in your wordToRGB() method replace the first line:

```
int c = (word[0] << 8) | (word[1]);
```

with

```
  int c = (word[0] << 8) | (word[1] & 0xFF);
```

The problem happens when you convert from byte to int. Example 1:

```
int a = 255;
println(binary(a));

int b = (byte) 255;
println(binary(b));
```

prints:

```
00000000000000000000000011111111
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

Example 2:

```
int a = 127;
println(binary(a));

int b = (byte) 127;
println(binary(b));
```

prints:

```
00000000000000000000000001111111
00000000000000000000000001111111
```

Processing pads with to the left with whatever your last bit was, so essentially after that, your | distorts all the values.

Comment: In the beginning I thought it would only pad with 1 so I was wondering why it ever happened to not show Red...

Comment: d'oh moment with the 0xFF mask :) Thanks Petros!

Answer (score 2):

`>>` is arithmetic shift, so it will sign extends the value. Use logic shift `>>>` instead

In C, there's no `>>>` operators, the right shift depends on implementation but most will do a logical shift if the variable is unsigned, so just cast or define it as unsigned

Comment: Thanks Lưu, that's handy (+1)

Comment: `>>` on unsigned is ***always*** a logical shift in C (after all, why would you sign-extend an integer that cannot possibly be negative?). It is *signed* that can be either arithmetic or logical.